# N56VZ: Subwoofer not working anymore

Tags: 12.04, sound, hardware, asus

I use Ubuntu 12.04 on Asus N56VZ, the subwoofer used to work doing the following trick advised by Sami:

> a. Add to rc.local
>
> echo 0x1e 0x99130112 > /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs
>
> echo 1 > /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/reconfig
>
> b. Add options snd-hda-intel model=asus-mode4 in /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
>
> c. Reboot
>
> d. Set the mode to "Analog Surround 5.1 output" in the sound settings panel

But a few weeks ago, the "Analog Surround 5.1 output" box does not appear anymore on the sound setting panel

I tride to install this driver: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS
But no result.

Here is my /etc/rc.local:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution  
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
fstrim -v /
fstrim -v /home
echo 0x1e 0x99130112 > /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs
echo 1 > /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/reconfig

exit 0
```

and my /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf:

```
# autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules

install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules

install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && {     /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && {     /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && {     /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-hda-intel model=asus-mode4"
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

after suspending computer sound card stops working. I can use headphones, but subwoofer and computer speakers doesn't work, after restarting it works. Any idea how to solve this? Without changes in /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf subwoofer doesnt work, but computers speakers works fine after several suspendings