# ubuntu 13.10 ASUS R552JV - CN195H external subwoofer not working

Tags: sound, asus, 13.10

i installed ubuntu 13.10 on my laptop ASUS R552JV - CN195H alongside windows 8.

on windows external subwoofer to this laptop is working but ubuntu doesnt recognize it (there is no sound from subwoofer). i searched for solution and i found some ([No sound from external subwoofer "Sonic Master" on an Asus N76VM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189304/no-sound-from-external-subwoofer-sonic-master-on-an-asus-n76vm), https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ASUS_N55SF, [N56VZ: Subwoofer not working anymore](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260223/n56vz-subwoofer-not-working-anymore)), but it was for other asus laptop series. i tried them, but it didnt work for me. 
in sound preferences, there is no option for 2.1 sound.

if someone could help me, i would be thankfull :)

Answer (score 0):

I got mine going - I explain what I did in [This AskUbuntu posting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/336026/asus-n56dp-sonic-master-subwoofer-not-working?lq=1) .

There are 2 parts to the problem: 1) Getting the low-level drivers working. The AMD drivers are broken in the 3.8 kernel but seem to work in the 3.11 kernel.

Once you get the low level drivers working the steps are the same for Intel and AMD machines.